# yui: creating yui menus dynamically by using a given list of items

Tags: loops, dynamic, menu, yui, loading

I want to create a yui menu dynamically by getting menu elements from list.

forexample I have a list

```
   MENULIST:
  MENUITEM1
  MENUITEM2
  MENUITEM3
  MENUITEM4
```

These menu items are objects  will inturn have sub menus and associated properties, functions like onclick etc  list for example

```
MENUITEM1----->SUBMENUITEM11,ONCLICK=SOMEFUNCTION()
                 SUBMENUITEM12,ONCLICK=SOMEFUNCTION()
                 SUBMENUITEM13,ONCLICK=SOMEFUNCTION()
  MENUITEM2----->SUBMENUITEM21,ONCLICK=SOMEFUNCTION()
                 SUBMENUITEM22,ONCLICK=SOMEFUNCTION()
```

i  will get these list at runtime ,soi need to load the menu dynamically. is there 
any option in the yui menu to do this looping over list and generating menu. than you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not at the moment since the NodeMenuNav it's just a Plugin. There are plans for a new Menu component which will support creating menu items from JavaScript. Ryan Grove recently contributed a Tree data structure on top of which a future Menu component can be built. He's also working on a new FocusManager, so it's all under work.

For now you need to create the markup yourself and then apply the NodeMenuNav Plugin. A good idea would be to use a template like Template.Micro. Check out the tmeplates User Guide: http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/template/. A Micro template for a menu could look like:

```
<div id="menu-1" class="yui3-menu">
  <div class="yui3-menu-content">
    <ul>
      <% Y.Array.each(this.menus, function (menu) { %>
        <li class="yui3-menuitem">
          <a class="yui3-menuitem-content" href="<%= menu.link %>"><%= menu.label %></a>
        </li>
      <% }); %>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```